# TypeScript: Iterating over the interface fields does not work

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to iterate over the keys of an object that has an interface, but TypeScript does not recognise the type of the key.

```
interface Resources {
  food?: number
  water?: number
  wood?: number
  coal?: number
  stone?: number
  metal?: number
  oil?: number
  power?: number
}

class Game {
  resources: Resources = {}

  addResources = (newResources: Resources) => {
    Object.keys(newResources).forEach(key => {
      // Error:(17, 11) TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Resources'.
     //  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Resources'.
      if (this.resources[key]) {
        this.resources[key] += newResources[key]
      } else {
        this.resources[key] = newResources[key]
      }
    })
  }
}
```

How should I type it so Typescript will understand the iteration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `Object.keys()` returns `string[]` and this is intentional https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12870

`(Object.keys(newResources) as Array<keyof Resources>).forEach(...)` for the rescue.

UPD

`(Object.keys(newResources) as Array<keyof typeof newResources>).forEach(...)` also helps.

Comment: Hmm, this is very, very strange. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The interface does not exist in the browser, TypeScipt is only a compiler concept. Once your code is compiled to JavaScript and running in the browser there is no concept of the interface left. The interface exists only to strongly type the code during development, it is completely lost at run time.

Comment: Yes, but Typescript complains about types specifically, which exist only at compile time too...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the compiler error add a dynamic property.

```
interface Resources {
  food?: number
  water?: number
  wood?: number
  coal?: number
  stone?: number
  metal?: number
  oil?: number
  power?: number
  [key: string]?: any
}
```

Comment: But then I could somewhere add a property with a typo, and compiler will not catch it...

Comment: Try creating an enum with the property names you want in it and the add that as the key type

Comment: `[key: string]?: any` does not define a property, it defines an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) that declares what types of keys and what types of values are valid for the type or interface.